# How can I prevent my title from overlapping my y-axis?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I need to make a boxplot and when making this, my title overlaps a value of my y-axis. How can I make sure this doesn't happen and move my title a bit more upwards? I also would like to make sure that the x-axis doesn't have a title, but I don't know how.

This is my code:

```
ax = df_values.boxplot(by = 'Win or lose')
ax.set_title('Box plots of the values which indicate if there is a winner or loser', weight='bold', size=20)
ax.set_ylabel('Value')
```

Comment: My value on the y-axis is very high, so it had 1e6 at the top left corner, which gets overlapped by my title.

Comment: Your problem cannot be reproduced from the code you included, and you haven't added in a screenshot of the plot in question so we can see what it looks like. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).